# Wrong information in my thesis

Tags: thesis, plagiarism

At the beginning im so sorry about what i did. But in literature review of the introduction part of my thesis i realized that i made a mistake :( 
It is about giving state-of-the-art part of my study area. When i describe a study i saw that, in paper it says that; 
"this paper describes the design for bla bla (paper)... we will evaluate the design(at conclusion)" but also in paper it says that for example;
"knee design take advantage of the fact that knee generate needed power bla bla.

But when i describe the paper i wrote that; "In[5], they emphasized that the design produced correct power" here the faily part :( they didn't evaluate but i mention that the design PRODUCED correct power. and 2 similar sentences:( 
For example i say: "ankle didn't produce unneeded power for bla bla".

but in paper it says; "ankle design take advantage of the fact that ankle doesn't produce large power for bla bla"

The case is here; they introduce the design or lets say, ,idea, proposes but i described as it produced that power etc but actually it wasn't made, those of them were ideas or claims of authors.
is it reason of revoking of my thesis later :( please help me.

Comment: If your thesis has been accepted just move on with your life. If it hasn't, fix it in revision. Nobody's read my thesis since I defended it and nobody's gonna read yours neither.

Answer (score 5):

If you aren't allowed to make a correction then you can't and it is what it is. But since it was accepted, there should be no issue for the thesis or for your degree.

However, in the future, if you do a publication that needs to cite the thesis, you can make a correction there. I assume, of course, that the error doesn't call your main result in to question. In that case you would need to either ignore the past or give a rather extensive update to your thesis in a new paper.

People make mistakes. People correct mistakes. Science moves on and advances.

Your thesis probably won't be the last piece of work that you do.

Comment: Does the error affect your main result, or is it just embarrassing?

Comment: Then there is no reason that you need to mention it, and no need to not mention it. It was an error, but not critical to the thesis. However, if you do, just say that you made an error of interpretation of past work. It wasn't intentional, nor an attempt to mislead. It has no effect on the outcome. The authors of the other study might want to complain to you and you can apologize to them if so, and correct yourself in any future work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think mis-quoting a particular reference will cause the revoking of your thesis.

Edit based on edited question:
If you are mis-representing the results ie changing the results to be for the ankle instead of the knee and then basing your results on that, then that could well be a concern.

Can you submit a correction to that section? You should check this with your advisor - they will know whether you should edit it or leave it...